# Command to know software version from terminal before installing

Tags: command-line, versions

Am trying to install Bibletime v2.9.2. I purged v2.8, added the crosswire ppa (ppa:pkgcrosswire/ppa) to my software sources and did a `sudo apt-get update`.

Since I don't have a fast internet connection, I wanted to know the Bibletime version available before installing it via terminal. I'd be glad if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanxs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-cache policy bibletime`.

This command will also tell you which source ships what version. Additionally, you'll see the priorities of the sources.